# react component for displaying the starry sky with constellations

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, components, web-component

Can you tell me if there is a React component (similar to Highmaps) for displaying the starry sky with constellations?

I need to display the contours of the constellations and correctly positioned stars and other objects in the sky (depending on the input data: Right ascension, Declination)

It is required to allow the user to select constellations and stars by clicking on the area of the sky, as it is done in Highmaps when selecting countries and cities on the map

for example:
[image]

Comment: You mention "Highmaps", but don't provide a link to that tool. Can you provide a link so we can see what you're trying to recreate?

Comment: Hi @Zhihar, Maybe it would be possible to create such a graph with basic Highcharts and scatter series? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/87bpts3n/

Comment: @Willow, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/all-maps - demo for a geographical map, and I need the same, but for a star map of the sky, where instead of the contours of the countries the contours of 88 constellations and stars are displayed

Comment: @ppotaczek, I would be happy to use highcharts, they have almost all the tools you need, even 3D (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/topojson-projection), but for the starry sky you need an inside view of the sphere, not outside. But I couldn't find star maps for highcharts :(

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe you will be able to create a custom map and use it in Highcharts? Please check this article: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps